# jQuery click listener does not work properly - CLOSED

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working through a Codacademy lesson and the interface is telling me that the jQuery click listener does not work properly. I don't understand why.

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src='script.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="button">change this</button>
            <div id="change_me">
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS code is:

```
#change_me {
color: green;
}
```

And my JS code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button").click(function() {
    //$(#change_me).text("I have been changed!");
     $(#change_me).text( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You're forgot quotes around `#change_me`

Comment: Recommend closing this because it's a simple typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss quotes `"` arround `id` selector, so you should replace:

```
$(#change_me)
```

By :

```
$("#change_me")
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    //$(#change_me).text("I have been changed!");
    $("#change_me").text( "Handler for .click() called." );
  });
});
```

```css
#change_me {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">change this</button>
<div id="change_me"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing quotation marks.

```
$("#change_me").text( "Handler for .click() called." );
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not using quotes Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button").click(function() {

      $("#change_me").text( "Handler for .click() called." );

   });
});
```